# Flow: Collection Filter Conditions Always Return Null Value

Tags: screen-flow

I'm trying to filter a collection of custom records called SelectedSchools_Select.

This collection contains three records and I know it is populating correctly because I can display it in tests and see the ID values in debugger.

I am trying to filter this collection using a Collection Filter to check for two checkbox fields as pictured below.

[image: flow image]

When I run this in debugger though, the filter ends up returning no records because it reads the value of both the Waive_Fee and Active fields as NULL, see below:

[image: Debugger]

Any idea how I can get it to read the field value and filter the results correctly?

Comment: Did you make sure your Get Records element is configured to include those fields, either by using the Retrieve All Fields option or the Let Salesforce Decide option?

Comment: Thanks! This was (sort of it) the collection I was filtering was coming from an Apex Action. I guess you can't filter those or can't filter them without further customizing the Apex.

I used a new Get Records element and that cleared it up. Ended up not even needing the filter with the redundant Get Records.

Comment: You can filter such collections only if the Apex returns those fields. Checkbook fields can never be null when retrieved, which was my clue. Happy to help!